# Overline text inside JButton

Tags: java, swing, text, fonts, jbutton

I know that if I want underline a text in a `JButton` I have to do something like this:

```
JButton myButton=new JButton("Test");
Font font = myButton.getFont();
Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
myButton.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
```

And, If I would overline a text? What should I do? Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

No need for the `Font` class here. You can use [HTML directly](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/html.html) and add the `<u>` and `<strike>` tags:

```
myButton = new JButton("<html><strike><u>Test</u></strike></html>");
```

Comment: Think the OP wanted a line over the text rather than thru the center...:)

Comment: @Reimeus I'm not strong with HTML, is there any tag responsible for adding a line *over* the text? :)

Comment: Don't think HTML will work here, only solution is custom one such as in camickr's answer...

Answer (score 1):

Just adding to @maroun's answer(I'm not allowed to comment). try using HTML directly.

```
myButton = new JButton ("<html><font style=\"text-decoration: overline;\">  Overline text</font></html>");
```

Comment: *"..try using HTML directly."*  Did **you** try that HTML/styles in a `JLabel`?  I haven't the time, but doubt it would render as intended (presuming the compilation error were fixed first, of course).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact there is compilation error due to " " used in the String passed as parameter in the JButton constructor.

Comment: `<html><div style="border-top: 1px solid #000000">Overline text</div></html>` will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `CompoundBorder`:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Using Compound Border");
Border lineBorder = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 0, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
CompoundBorder border = new CompoundBorder(button.getBorder(), lineBorder);
button.setBorder( border );
```